# How can I save a user's selected choice on refresh Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to save a user's choice which but on refresh or navigating to another page, the submission had been removed.

How can I save the user's submission so it won't reset/change unless the user chooses to?

*I.e. if someone chooses AUD, that choice will remain submitted on refresh/navigation/login/logout.*

**FORM**

```
class CurrencyForm(forms.Form):
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(initial=('USD', 'USD'), choices=['USD', 'AUD', 'GBP' 'CAD'], label='Choose Currency:')
```

**VIEW**

```
class MyDashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        form_c = CurrencyForm(prefix='form_c')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'form_c': form_c,
        })

    def post(self, request):

        currency = 'USD'

        form_c = CurrencyForm(request.POST, prefix='form_c')

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form_c.is_valid():
                currency = form_c.cleaned_data['currency']
        
        rates = {'USD': 1.0, 'AUD': 1.321, 'GBP': 0.764, 'CAD': 1.249}

        deposit = 10000 / rates[currency]

        context = {
            'deposit': deposit
        }

        return render(request, 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```
<span>
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form_c.as_p }}
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
</form>
</span>
<span class="text-xl">${{ deposit }}</span>
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to use `localStorage or sessionStorage in javascript` or django session in server side.let me know if you need a code for that.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I don't know how to write in Javascript, but if you could direct me on what the best approach is would be much appreciated.

Comment: okay then you can use django session if you want.here is a good tutorial that you can  refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions